# Problem with using string variable on React-bootstrap's OverlayTrigger placement attribute

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have an unexpected error with the OverlayTrigger component from React-Bootstrap ver. 5.1.1
I'm trying to create my own customized button component using overlaytrigger and a button. Everything works as I want except using a variable for the tooltip placement. It might just be because I am a typeScript noob but I don't know what to do when i see error messages like this. Has anyone else seen this problem before, know a workaround or perhaps know what to do with error messages like these in general?

[image: placement attribute on overlaytrigger not allowing string variables in typescript.]

[image: Error tooltip explaining string is not allowed.]

[image: It clearly works with a hard coded string.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement variable for OverlayTrigger is a type which is declared as **Placement**, you are able to inspect any type if you want for more information *(e.g. by pressing F12 on the input variable)*.

For your example you are able to specify placement with string value `"bottom"` because this value is derived from **BasePlacement** `"right" | "top" | "bottom" | "left"` and the value is able to resolve to this type.

However when trying to set your variable `{tooltipPlacement}` it is resolved as type of string, because this is what it's declared as, your compiler gives you this information.

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Placement | undefined'.ts(2322)

#### Solution

One way to solve this is to tell the compiler what type you want to cast this variable to, you know that `"bottom"` is a valid value to resolve to type of **Placement**.

`placement={tooltipPlacement as Placement}`

Comment: I've tried this solution and get:

TS2304: Cannot find name 'Placement'.

I'm having the same problem trying to set the size on a Modal. There is no such thing as Size.

How do I access the Placement type?

Comment: @Sonnerz 'Placement' is declared type for OverlayTrigger and if you are using react-bootstrap there is no such type on a Modal. I looked into their [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modal-props) for the Modal and there is actually a property called size that accepts the values 'sm' | 'lg' | 'xl'. If you are using react-bootstrap's Modal you should give that a try :)

Comment: No, I get that error when trying to access 'Placement' on the OverlayTrigger and I get the same error trying to access 'size' on the Modal.

Comment: @Sonnerz Oh i see, well it's a bit difficult to help without me seeing your code i'm afraid, if i were you i would ask a question togheter with your code. If you then paste your link in this comment section i can then maybe take a look :)